# Non-Flash Audio Plugins for CKeditor

Tags: audio, plugins, mp3, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am looking to find a non-flash based audio plugin for ckeditor. I tried making my own custom plugin but was unsuccessful..I would much rather prefer to find a pre-made plugin.

Ideally, I would like to upload an mp3 and be able be able to place on page with a non- flash based player ( js,jquery, ect.. ).

I am trying to move away from flash as much as possible for optimum mobile compatibility.

Current setup = ckeditor + ckeditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ckeditor.com/addon/Audio 
check this out if you still need it

Comment: Sorry for the uber late response. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question back in 2015!